# iOS 7 UINavigationController transition to UITableView: black-translucent layer during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

in my new iOS app I'd like to use a fixed background for the entire app and its views.

When clicking the navigation item to show up the settings table controller an ugly black-translucent layer or something like this appears in a fraction of a second on the whole screen until the animation is done.

Any idea to remove this undesired behaviour?
Thank you!

**Demo:**

[image]

[better .mp4 version of the demo @ Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ca5g0q0et3zxk2y/Ohne%20Titel3.mp4?dl=0)

**edit:**
The UINavigationController contains the background image.

My Settings TableViewController was modified like this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the standard `UINavigationController` push animation in iOS 7. When a new ViewController is pushed onto the stack, it overlays itself on top of the previous ViewController, with a slight shadow underneath it.

The solution I think is to implement your own transition. Like this:

Create a new `UINavigationController` class, I name it `CustomNavigationController`

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
@interface UINavigationController (Retro)

- (void)pushViewControllerCustom:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Retro)

- (void)pushViewControllerCustom:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.2;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    //Fade here look nice, no more black shadow stuff
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    [self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
}

@end
```

To use it:

```
- (IBAction)barButtonItemPressed:(id)sender
{
    TableViewController *tableView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewControllerCustom:tableView];
}
```